# Connection object close() doesn't close the connection properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, driver

I'm using the following snippet to connect with database

```
private Connection getConnection(JspWriter out, String host, String dbname,
        String port, String user, String pwd) {
    try {
        if (host == null || dbname == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid host or dbname"); 
        }
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname; 
        String clazz = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"; 
        Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName(clazz).newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Exception occured while get connection :"+ e);
   }
    return null;
}
```

Once the query is executed I'm closing the connection object

```
private JSONArray executeQuery(JspWriter out, Connection connection,String query, Object[] params) throws Exception {

PreparedStatement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    //connection = getConnection();
    st = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    int c = 1;
    for (Object param : params) {
        st.setObject(c++, param);
    }
    rs = st.executeQuery();
    if (rs == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    List<String> columns = getColumnNames(meta);
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    while (rs.next()) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (String column : columns) {
            obj.put(column, rs.getObject(column));
        }
        json.put(obj);
    }
    return json;
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while execute query" + e);
} finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        } 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            //Print exception
    }
    try {
        if (st != null) {
            st.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            //Print exception
    } 
    try {
        if(connection != null) {
                connection.close();
        }
        if(connection.isClosed()) {
            connection = null;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
                //Print exception
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Though I've closed connection with `.close()` method. And I'm making sure that the connection is closed with `connection.closed()` and it returns true - indicating that connection is closed successfully.

Once the connection limit reaches the maximum - I'm getting `DB Connection Exhausted` and my server couldn't make further connections.

Can someone help me to debug this further please.

Comment: Why are you registering the driver every time this method is called? You only need to do it once.

Comment: @EJP : Yeah, you are right. I'll correct it in my code. But will that cause any impact?

Comment: Why are you using the ancient driver name `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`? It has been called `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` since forever (and since the new 8.x driver, `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, and the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` class is no longer available)?

Comment: And while you're at it, the `Class.forName()` hasn't been required since 2007. I suggest you find yourself some up-to-date reference material. And Connector/J JAR files.

Comment: Okay Mark Rotteveel and EJP.. will look into it..

Comment: @EJP In a web application (as used by the op) it may - defending on where the driver is deployed) still be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

#### Not strictly related. Use try-with-resources

Start using the [try-with-resources syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which was introduced in Java 7:

```java
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    // ...
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {

        // ...
    }
}
```

It's much more convenient and less error prone.

#### Whose responsibility is it to close a connection?

The responsibility to close a connection is always with the logic that opens it. Your method shouldn't close the connection if it doesn't acquire it. The caller should (whose logic you haven't posted). Ideally, you'd be using a connection pool anyway, but that might be off topic here.

An example:

```java
// This logic opens the connection by calling getConnection()
// It must also close the connection again, e.g. with try-with-resources
try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
  doSomething(connection);
}

...
// This logic didn't open a connection. It receives it from someone else
// It mustn't close the connection!
void doSomething(Connection connection) {

  // But if other resources are opened, then they must be closed here:
  try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
    doSomething(stmt);
  }
}

..
// Again, this method didn't open the statement, it shouldn't close it
void doSomething(Statement statement) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: But how does that make a difference?

Comment: @Natasha: See my update. The problem isn't really in the code you posted, but elsewhere. I suggest you use a connection pool...

Comment: I'm trying to make this clear. `the responsibility to close a connection is always with the logic that opens it` - but the object passed as a reference here is (similar to pass by reference) - so we should ideally close where ever (either the caller or the callee) right?

Comment: @Natasha: OK, I've added an example. This has nothing to do with passing by reference, but with resource management. I really suggest reading up on this topic. You have a resource management problem somewhere in your application, including, but not only in the code you've posted. If this isn't properly understood first, it's quite impossible to fix the problem you're having.

Comment: @Natasha: Cool! Hang in there, at some point, it will make sense :)

Comment: It is another query which did not return (or) close the connection properly in my code which caused this `Database Connection Exhausted` exception... Thanks a lot for the replies :-)